# Java setting VideoCapture.set(CAP_PROP_FOURCC, codec value)

Tags: java, opencv, video-capture, codec

I want to set a Codec for `VideoCapture`.

I found [THIS LIST](http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php) of codecs.
Now since `VideoCapture.set(CAP_PROP_FOURCC, double value)` expects a `double` for the codec value and I haven't found a way in JavaCV to convert the codecs to `double` values I would like to know **how do I pass the relevant codec to `VideoCapture.set(CAP_PROP_FOURCC, double value)`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better late then never...

I came around the same problem when I realized I would get MUCH better performance when fetching data from the camera as an mpeg stream (~10FPS with default YUY2, ~30FPS with mpeg). 
The trick with setting FOURCC is, to first determine the "code" needed for the respective FourCC codec and THEN setting the property "Videoio.CAP_PROP_FOURCC" to the determined codec. For any given codec, the associated "code" can be retrieved via "VideoWriter" class.

```
    int fourcc = VideoWriter.fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G');
    videoCapture.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, fourcc);
    videoCapture.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, CAP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    videoCapture.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, CAP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
```

Keep in mind that, you have to **set the FourCC BEFORE adjusting the frame size**, otherwise it has no effect. 
The code above is for openCV 3.0. This page (although for C++) pointed me into the right direction: http://answers.opencv.org/question/6805/how-to-get-mjpeg-compression-format-from-webcam/